# How to set Socket Timeouts in ruby's UNIXSocket?

Tags: ruby, sockets, network-programming, unix-socket

I want to set the SO_SNDTIMEO on a Ruby Socket.

The unix socket class does not seem to allow that? How does one do this.

Comment: First Google result for [SO_SNDTIMEO ruby](http://www.google.com/search?q=SO_SNDTIMEO+ruby) seems to explain it: http://www.mikeperham.com/2009/03/15/socket-timeouts-in-ruby/

Comment: that article explains for TCPSocket, I am looking for UnixSocket